# Prevent scrolling to input when filling it in Android Phonegap App

Tags: android, cordova, input, keypress, preventdefault

Im using Telerik AppBuilder with Cordova version 3.5

My problem is, I dont want that the webview in my app is scrolling. Every time scrolling is needed I want to use iScroll and I will handle scrolling by my code.

If an input gets focus and isnt visible because of scrolling in iScroll, the app automatically scrolls the webview.

I prevented scrolling on focusing inputs in android with this code in the manifest:

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan|stateVisible" />
```

And to prevent scrolling while typing, my next idea was:

1. prevent default on keypress
2. store pressed key
3. scroll to my input in iScroll
4. paste key into input (now its sure visible and levels above will not scroll the webview)

But following code in android v4.4.4 does not prevent default:

```
    $input.on( 'keypress', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
```

Is this a bug?
Is there any workaround for this?

edit:

To see what property the browser is changing, so that I can change it back, I looked at a few elements, but cant find it:

1. $(window).scrollTop() -> not changing.
2. margin-top and top of elemets used by iScroll -> not changing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, 
but I think your problem is that when the keypress event is triggered, the 'keydown' event has already been send to the input, which is the event that sends the actual key. Keypress get triggered after that while holding character keys.
so you should try to preventDefault the 'keydown' event and probably also 'keypress' in case of repeated letters while holding.

```
$input.on( 'keydown keypress', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```